# Customize Sharepoint Search Alert Email Template

Tags: search

I am trying to modify the email template for a sharepoint **search alert**. I have done the following:

Made a copy of the following file:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\alerttemplate.xml
```

Renamed it to "alerttemplatetest.xml" and made my changes, then ran the following command:

```
stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -url http://sharepointsite -filename "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\alerttemplatestest.xml"
```

Then I did the following:

- IIS Reset
- Restart Sharepoint Timer Service

I then relized that the search alert does not use the same alerttemplate.xml file that the other alerts use because the **template name is OSS.Search** and that does not exist in the file.

In summary my question is how can I edit the template for the Sharepoint Search Alert Emails or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also not aware of how to change the Search Alert Templates by modifying some XML. However it is possible to create these templates using C# as explained here:

- [Customize search alert email](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/4a2844dc-0a25-4214-a200-16a474c1aa54)

The important thing to note in the post is the  [`SearchAlert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.searchalert.aspx) class with which you can create daily/weekly alerts.

Also there is a very good article about the inner workings of Search alerts on MSDN:

- [Working with Search Alerts in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh161512%28v=office.14%29.aspx)